# Multiple Inequalities in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inequalities

Complete ruby noob.

I have a value which I want to check against several numbers (1,4,7) and if it equals any of them, return false.

right now I'm using:

```
if $my_variable_class[1] != 1 && $my_variable_class[1] != 4 && $my_variable_class[1] != 7
```

I've got a shit-ton of numbers to check for inequality against.  Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using a global variable with the `$`? It's not exactly considered best-practice.

Comment: It's actually as part of a class.  Edited code example to better reflect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe `unless [1,4,7].include?($my_variable[1])` will do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

```
unless [1,4,7].include? $my_variable[1]
  do_smth
end
```