# is there a nicer way to phrase the following logical expression in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Inequalities in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257379/multiple-inequalities-in-ruby)

Hi All,  I have an ugly logical expression, and I just know there's a much nicer, more concise way to phrase this in ruby:

```
some_variable == 1 || some_variable == 2 || some_variable == 4
```

All suggestions welcomed,  Thanks

Comment: Probably gazilions of duplicates, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257379/multiple-inequalities-in-ruby

Comment: more duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420973/simple-ruby-or-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[1,2,4].include? some_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,3,4]
a.indclude?(some_variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something conditionally, you can also do:

```
case some_variable
when 1, 2, 4
    blahblah
else
    blahblah
end
```